# Installed root certificate authority doesn't appear to be working?

Tags: arch-linux, openssl, certificates

- OS : archlinux
- Openssl dir : /etc/ssl

I just installed a root certificates authority. The `xxx.pem` and `yyy.0` file exists in the `/etc/ssl/certs` folder. Then I verify the `vimeo.com:443` via bash:

```
$ openssl s_client  -connect vimeo.com:443
```

It shows:

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
    Session-ID: 001635EF0132A25577F3799825F2698A8FEDCDF916393DB44E9FCC5701D5E310
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: C5AA72B1E0A805AA950D1E0EFC7565F0EF3949618927EA84081B65E65B664C7AB803757CFF1CB12333CB8FC7D8298BA6
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1394981067
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

And if I explicitly set the CA file:

```
$ openssl s_client  -connect vimeo.com:443 -CAfile XXX.pem

SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
    Session-ID: BF58BED9C13FF42E5DDEBC938CED703CD81A96EC59442B91FC6669D31D13E510
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 197D80168908A8491C26F27B1C5AAA29BE2DC9CCBB8B840BAA45FCE683BDDB95133E58A48EDAC5AF820C97C948D436E2
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1394981110
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Have I successfully installed the certificates? Why must I specify the CA file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me on Fedora 19.

```
$ openssl s_client  -connect vimeo.com:443 < /dev/null
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
    Session-ID: 2345C651AB00DC97DF7390227CFA1EE8FD4F35EDCB142C4EB053F01380890514
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: B1BD06863BD3CEF2C2963AF47E5269DFE19A650A27A1A7D9032D361D34C3AFC914E59FBABEAE8087AD47D6EFC067548D
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1394988228
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

I would debug your issue further using `strace` to confirm that `openssl` is picking up the added `.pem` files from the directory you think it is.

```
$ strace -s 2000 -o ssl.log openssl s_client  -connect vimeo.com:443 < /dev/null
```

You can then interrogate the resulting log file, `ssl.log`, looking to find out where `openssl` the executable is accessing it's PEM files.

```
open("/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10906, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c0277e000
...
open("/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=235586, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c0277e000
...
```

I'd also pay special attention to the permissions of the files you've added as well as making sure that `openssl`'s configuration file, `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf`, is referencing the correct directory:

```
...
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir     = /etc/pki/CA       # Where everything is kept
certs       = $dir/certs        # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir     = $dir/crl      # Where the issued crl are kept
database    = $dir/index.txt    # database index file.
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This page https://www.archlinux.org/news/ca-certificates-update/ says basically copy it in `/etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/` and then run `update-ca-trust`.

If you use Manjaro instead of Arch, for some reason that doesn't work, but if you put them in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/` instead, it works fine. (and I think I like it better on Manjaro... you can just rm the file and `update-ca-trust` again and it is gone, but on arch it seems to insert and copy it in many places so it ends up in at least 11 files in the end)